# Implement a Material CDK based Drag and Drop Functionality

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, web-frontend, angular-cdk

Kindly look at this link:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/nabbkobrxrn?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-enter-predicate-example.ts
Within this above example I want to acheive the following:

1. Out of the "Available numbers" list i need to be able to put only
   one number in the even list (not create a list of numbers);
2. Restrict drag and drop within the lists;
3. Whenever the number in the Even list is replaced with another drop from the Available numbers list, the present value in the even
   numbers list goes back to the original place in the available
   numbers list.
4. Store the current value in the even list to a variable and display it separately.

I tried something from my end , I can get the requirement 4. somehow but the others are not achieved.
Would be of immense help if anyone please edit the code and share the code path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code, here are the things I did

1. Added an object that contains the array and the list name to cdkDropListData
2. Modified the drop method logic to only handle the transfer of items from one list to the other

Hope this helps.

```js
all = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
even = [10];
originalIndex = 9;

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<{ val: string[]; list: string }>) {

  if (event.previousContainer !== event.container) {

    if (event.container.data.list === 'even') {
      if (event.container.data.val.length === 0) {
        transferArrayItem(
          event.previousContainer.data.val,
          event.container.data.val,
          event.previousIndex,
          event.currentIndex
        );
      } else {

        if(event.container.data.val.length){
          transferArrayItem(
            event.container.data.val,
            event.previousContainer.data.val,
            0,
            this.originalIndex
          );

          event.previousIndex = event.previousIndex >= this.originalIndex ? event.previousIndex + 1 : event.previousIndex
        }

        transferArrayItem(
          event.previousContainer.data.val,
          event.container.data.val,
          event.previousIndex,
          event.currentIndex
        );

        this.originalIndex = event.previousIndex;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div
  id="all"
  cdkDropList
  [cdkDropListData]="{val: all, list: 'all'}"
  cdkDropListConnectedTo="even"
  class="example-list"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="noReturnPredicate"
>
  <div
    class="example-box"
    *ngFor="let number of all"
    [cdkDragData]="number"
    cdkDrag
  >
    {{number}}
  </div>
</div>


<div
  id="even"
  cdkDropList
  [cdkDropListData]="{val: even, list: 'even'}"
  cdkDropListConnectedTo="all"
  class="example-list"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="evenPredicate"
>
  <div
    class="example-box"
    *ngFor="let number of even"
    cdkDrag
    [cdkDragData]="number"
  >
    {{number}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My first two criterion are fulfilled thanks...viz. (Out of the "Available numbers" list i need to be able to put only one number in the even list (not create a list of numbers);

Restrict drag and drop within the lists;) but , after the first attempt to drag from the available list the even no. when dragged gives us the succeding number on the even list. Like say i first take  4 from the Av. List and add it to even list it works fine, but then the 10 from even list goes to topmost posn. on available list and hence if i drop say 6 from av.list to even list value 7 gets registered. Kindly help

Comment: I have updated the ts code, please check and let me know if it works.

Comment: Now the functionality of drag and drop works. thanks, however, when i say drop 6 from av. list to the even list the 10 goes on top of the available list instead of settling below 9.

Comment: Also check this edit i did by removing the even predicate criterion:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yam6dj?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-enter-predicate-example.ts                                                                                                               Try dropping 3 from the available list to even list (it works), then try with 4 from available list and see that 3 remains unchanged, however if you drop 5 then that gets set. this is happening for consecutive items from the available list.

Comment: I have fixed the problems, few points to keep in mind if you have one item already in the 2nd list, that item will be moved to the index with which originalIndex was initialised. In the previous case, it was 0 so '10' was moved to the top.

Comment: did the solution work?

Comment: Not reaaly, as " Try dropping 3 from the available list to even list (it works), then try with 4 from available list and see that 3 remains unchanged, however if you drop 5 then that gets set. this is happening for consecutive items from the available list." remains still

Comment: I had updated the ts code in the answer, replace the drop method code and give it a try

Comment: this now works perfectly.great work!